# How to set VSCode settings, so that an import is possible?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, import

I have cloned a github repo and a project structure of it is a following (There are some files and subfolders in Lib\site-packages, Scripts\ and static\ ):

```
-e_commerce\
   --.idea\
   --e_commerce_website\
      ----.gitignore.txt
      ----db.slite3
      ----manage.py
      ----requirements.txt
      ---.idea\
      ---.vs\
         ----e_commerce\v16\.suo
         ----ProjectSettings.json
         ----slnx.sqlite
         ----VSWorkspaceState.json
      ---e_commerce_env\
         ----Include\
         ----Lib\site-packages\
         ----Scripts\
         ----pyvenv.cfg
      ---ecom\
         ----__pycache__\
         ----___init___.py
         ----asgi.py
         ----settings.py
         ----urls.py
         ----wsgi.py
      ---static\
      ---store\
         ----__pycache__\
         ----migrations\
         ----templates\
         ----___init__.py
         ----admin.py
         ----apps.py
         ----models.py
         ----tests.py
         ----urls.py
         ----views.py
```

For example, in apps.py (and other files) an error occurs:
*Import "django.apps" could not be resolved from sourcePylance.*
... which shows because of the line:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
```

I have created an environment e_commerce_env which works successfully when I run the server from cmd / powershell. I checked where django is installed when being inside the env, and it turns out that the path is equal to:
*c:\users\user\desktop\e_commerce\e_commerce_website\e_commerce_env\lib\site-packages*
Should I set this path somewhere in VSCode to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set the Python interpreter in VSCode. See this link:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment

This will essentially tell VSCode to use the same interpreter that you are using at the command line.

Even though the command prompt you are using is within VSCode, you essentially have two places where the environment needs to be activated/selected.

Answer (score 0):

This error is produced because it's not detecting the installed modules, it's a Pylance (VS code editor) error, not an error in your code.

You've to have the correct Python environment selected for Pylance to detect the installed modules. Tho, [it should switch to the correct env by default](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/330), but you can try disabling and enabling the extension in case it's bugged, if not, [try selecting manually the desired environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-environments).

Answer (score 0):

Click here to select the interpreter:

[image]

You can refer to the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) for more details.